# QWebEngineView крашит приложение при открытии YouTube

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview, qwebengine

Если попытаться открыть другую ссылку, например `google.com`, то всё работает. Но при открытии конкретно `youtube.com` приложение крашится без ошибок: `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`. Версии: `Python 3.7.9`, `PyQt5 5.15.6`, `PyQtWebEngine 5.15.6`.

Код запуска:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(widget)
        view.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.youtube.com"))  # https://www.google.com
        layout.addWidget(view)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.resize(450, 450)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Обновлено 05.04.2023:**

Проблема всё ещё актуальна. Были проведены тесты на другом ПК: `Python 3.8`, `PyQt5 5.15.6`, `PyQtWebEngine 5.15.5` и на нём всё работало корректно (**версии Windows идентичные**). На ПК где изначально были краши проблема осталась, даже после полной переустановки `python` и всех пакетов соответственно. Проверялось на `Python 3.8` и `Python 3.9`. Также если сразу открыть google, ввести в поиск youtube и перейти на сайт, то тоже происходит краш.

Comment: Попробуйте self.manuals_view, вот работающий код https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67521837/how-to-open-the-youtube-link-from-a-youtube-video-embed-in-a-pyqt5-widget-in-pyt

Comment: @СергейКох `self.manuals_view` ничего не поменяло. Код из примера тоже крашится, если ссылка ютуба стоит, с другой нормально.

Comment: @Афродита, cкиньте ссылку на которой крашится

Comment: @DaniilLoban в коде она указана - `"https://www.youtube.com"` и на других ссылках ютуба.

Comment: У меня Ваш код запускается, выводится в консоль некая инфа но приложение не падает. 0xC0000005 - если я не ошибаюсь ошибка доступа к памяти в Windows - возникает, когда программа в Windows пытается получить доступ к местоположению или данным из места, которое ей не назначено. (у меня Linux)

Comment: @DaniilLoban у меня в Windows 7 все работает.

Comment: Предполагаю, что ошибка не в этом коде

Comment: @Афродита добавьте в вопрос полный стек ошибки, может что-то станет понятнее

Comment: Я переписал на C++, запустил под Ubuntu 20.04 - все работает!

Comment: @DaniilLoban а как мне получить полный стек ошибки, если оно просто крашится, в консоль выводится текст, который я прикрепила и всё.

Comment: в Windows можно посмотреть логи через панель администрирования, там видно больше деталей по поводу краша, искать по приложению либо python либо qt либо по времени падения https://beehosting.pro/ru/prosmotr-sobytij-v-windows/

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QWebEngineView>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();

    QWebEngineView *manuals_view = new QWebEngineView(widget);

    manuals_view->setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com"));  // https://www.google.com
    layout->addWidget(manuals_view);

    setLayout(layout);
    resize(450, 450);
    show();

}

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

С Qt 6.2.3 все работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
с Qt 5.12.6 при первом запуске были  ошибки, но дальше нормально все пошло

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а зачем вы переписывали на C++,?

Comment: У меня не запустился скрипт на Python. Не хватает библиотек. Да и вообще по-моему на C++ все стабильнее работает. Разве нет? Может быть автор вопроса запустит код на плюсах и все заработает.  Я на самом деле и отвечать не хотел, достаточно комментария, но к комментарию нельзя прикрепить фото и код. Если мешает, я удалю.